Why do we still need locks with atomic operations?
The example code is as follows:
class ResourcePool{
public:   
    ...
    static inline ResourcePool* singleton()
    {
        ResourcePool* p = _singleton.load(butil::memory_order_consume);
        if (p) {
            return p;
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&_singleton_mutex);
        p = _singleton.load(butil::memory_order_consume);
        if (!p) {
            p = new ResourcePool();
            _singleton.store(p, butil::memory_order_release);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_singleton_mutex);
        return p;
    }
private:
    ....
    static butil::static_atomic<ResourcePool*> _singleton;
    static pthread_mutex_t _singleton_mutex;
};

Butil:: memoryreorder_consume is the encapsulated boost memory order for memoryreorder_consume
The first question
In a multi-core and multi-threaded environment, the first "butil:: memoryreorder_consume" ensures the order of instructions and prevents other threads from dereferencing p before obtaining the p pointer?
Second question:
If the ResourcePool already exists, return  p=_singleton. load (but il:: memoryreorder_consume) between them If it is not created later, then create it. The subsequent  _singleton. store (p, but il:: memoryreorder-release) It should have been notified to other threads, as long as other threads  _singleton. load (p, but il:: memoryreorder-acquire) This is not a lockless implementation, why add a lock?
If locking is necessary to ensure that  p=_singleton. load (butil:: memoryreorder_consume) For the unique access, then the subsequent  _singleton. store (p, but il:: memoryreorder-release) What's the use of it?

What you've got there is an example of double checked locking, which is notoriously difficult to do correctly. The goal of double checked locking is to ensure that no thread ever has to lock the _singleton_mutex after the _singleton member has been assigned.
The purpose of the mutex is to prevent more than one thread from constructing a new ResourcePool(). That's a complex operation, and there simply is no other way to turn the constructor call and the _singleton assignment into a single, atomic operation except by using a mutex.
You would not need the mutex if you didn't mind making an optimistic version of the singleton function. An optimistic version potentially could allow more than one thread to construct a new ResourcePool, but it would guarantee that all of the callers would agree on which one was the authentic one, and it would guarantee that all of the extra ResourcePool objects would be deleted without ever being used.
The purpose of the atomic variable, of course, is to provide a lock-free way to ensure that once _singleton has been assigned, no thread will ever mistakenly think that it has not been assigned.
